# Android - Handling event on an add button issue

Tags: android

I want to insert text from field into a `String` array every time the add button is pressed, and when done so, the field should empty itself for a new string.

Here is my code:

*Editor note: no code provided as example, only a screenshot of the code*

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Shortened the title and included the screenshot within the question.

Comment: You don't say what the problem is. What do you see when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Is the add function ever called? Otherwise you are sitting with a button without an onClickListener. 
Try assigning The onClickListener in oncreate instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is in the inCreate method.Just wanted to know if what I intend to do is correct logically or not